# Reducing Memory Usage lots of Floats

Tags: sensors, code-optimization, memory-usage

Im using an Arduino Uno - All code at github.com/robbrad/AirQuality

Current sketch usage:

```
Sketch uses 23186 bytes (71%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1428 bytes (69%) of dynamic memory, leaving 620 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

I wouldn't normally just spam code for a optimisation - but im looking to get about 10% memory back from this sketch

It basically checks a bunch of sensors sets the values to floats, build a string and posts that to a php page where some more processing happens.

I have tried everything to my knowledge but I just cant think of a smarter way to use less memory.

I tried an array, a function to build the data string, using one float and concatenating it to the string when it set

I even thought of reducing the Math.h include to just the math functions I was using

Maybe im just reaching the little boards limits (which are pretty good anyway :) ! )

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MutichannelGasSensor.h"
#include "HP20x_dev.h"
#include "KalmanFilter.h"

unsigned char ret = 0;

/* Instance */
KalmanFilter t_filter;    //temperature filter
KalmanFilter p_filter;    //pressure filter
KalmanFilter a_filter;    //altitude filter

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
IPAddress server(192, 168, 0, 30); // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
//char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 40);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;


#define Vc 4.95
//the number of R0 you detected just now
#define R0 35.54
#define DHTPIN A1     // what pin we're connected to

// Uncomment whatever type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

int pin = 8;
unsigned long duration;
unsigned long starttime;
unsigned long sampletime_ms = 2000;//sampe 30s&nbsp;;
unsigned long lowpulseoccupancy = 0;
float ratio = 0;
float concentration = 0;
String data = "";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  delay(150);
  HP20x.begin();
  delay(100);

  /* Determine HP20x_dev is available or not */
  ret = HP20x.isAvailable();

  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  starttime = millis();//get the current time;
  //Serial.println("power on!");


  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

  //if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
  //  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(10000);
  // Serial.println("connecting...");
  //}
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  //delay(1000);
  //Serial.println("connecting...");



  // Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());


  gas.begin(0x04);//the default I2C address of the slave is 0x04
  gas.powerOn();
  //Serial.print("Firmware Version = ");
  //Serial.println(gas.getVersion());
  //Serial.println("Particles\tRS\tHCHO (PPM)\tNH3 (PPM)\tCO (PPM)\tNO2     (PPM)\tC3H8 (PPM)\tC4H10 (PPM)\tCH4 (PPM)\tH2 (PPM)\tC2H5OH (PPM)");
  dht.begin();
  delay(10000);

}

void loop() {

  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    //  Serial.print(c);
  }

  float HATemp2;
  float HAPres2;
  float HAAlt2;
  float d;

  if (OK_HP20X_DEV == ret)
  {
    unsigned long HATemp = HP20x.ReadTemperature();
    d = HATemp / 100.0;
    HATemp2 = t_filter.Filter(d);

    unsigned long HAPres = HP20x.ReadPressure();
    d = HAPres / 100.0;
    HAPres2 = p_filter.Filter(d);

    unsigned long HAAlt = HP20x.ReadAltitude();
    d = HAAlt / 100.0;
    HAAlt2 = a_filter.Filter(d);

  }

  duration = pulseIn(pin, LOW);
  lowpulseoccupancy = lowpulseoccupancy + duration;



  if ((millis() - starttime) >= sampletime_ms) //if the sampel time = = 30s
  {
    ratio = lowpulseoccupancy / (sampletime_ms * 10.0); // Integer percentage 0=&gt;100

    d = 1.1 * pow(ratio, 3) - 3.8 * pow(ratio, 2) + 520 * ratio + 0.62; // using spec sheet curve
    //Serial.print("concentration = ");



   lowpulseoccupancy = 0;
    starttime = millis();
  }



 //Serial.print("\t");
  //HCHO

  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  double Rs = (1023.0 / sensorValue) - 1;

  double ppm = pow(10.0, ((log10(Rs / R0) - 0.0827) / (-0.4807)));
  //Serial.print("HCHO ppm = ");

  //MultiChannel Gas
  float NH3 = gas.measure_NH3();
  float CO = gas.measure_CO();
  float NO2 = gas.measure_NO2();
  float C3H8 = gas.measure_C3H8();
  float C4H10 = gas.measure_C4H10();
  float CH4 = gas.measure_CH4();
  float H2 = gas.measure_H2();
  float C2H5OH = gas.measure_C2H5OH();


  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  data = String("dust=") + d + "&rs=" + Rs + "&hcho=" + ppm + "&nh3=" + NH3 + "&co=" + CO + "&no2=" + NO2 + "&c3h8=" + C3H8 + "&c4h10=" + C4H10 + "&ch4=" + CH4 + "&h2=" + H2 + "&c2h5oh=" + C2H5OH + "&temp=" + t + "&hum=" + h + "&HATemp=" + HATemp2 + "&HAPres=" + HAPres2 + "&HAAlt=" + HAAlt2;

  //Serial.println(data);


  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println(F("connected"));
    client.println(F("POST /air_add.php HTTP/1.1"));
    client.println(F("Host:  192.168.0.30"));
    client.println(F("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0"));
    client.println(F("Connection: close"));
    client.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"));
    client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
    client.println(data.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(data);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("could not connect"));
  }

  Serial.println(data);

  if (client.connected()) {
    client.stop();
  }


  delay(300000);
}
```

Comment: For which Arduino board? Are you trying to reduce ram or flash memory? What does the compiler say about ram and flash memory usage? Those few float variables on the stack are not the problem. The libraries might use a lot of memory. If no library uses the 'String' object, then you should try to avoid that. You can also send bare sensor data, and do the calculation and processing in the server.

Comment: It’s an Uno. The compiler didn’t complain but it’s right on the 70% and 69% limi for both respectively. I had a quick look at the libraries but not seeing anything jumping out at me. Maybe I’ll make a sketch with just the libraries to see just their usage

Comment: Please update your question with the extra information. You could add links to the used (non-Arduino) libraries, so we can have a look at them. For an Arduino Uno, you better get rid of the 'String' object. Even though that would result into 20 lines of code or more. The Ethernet shield is mostly used with an Arduino Mega 2560 or a Arduino Due, because the Uno has not enough memory.

Comment: Done - https://github.com/robbrad/AirQuality

Comment: Thanks, but those are only the *.h files, not the used libraries. I suggest to remove the 'String' class, and if that is not enough then replace the Arduino Uno with a board that has more memory (you probably are going to do that some day anyway).

Comment: Just added the cpp files

Comment: Why do you want to get 10% back? Even if the program memory is 99% full it won't cause any problems, unless you want to add more things. Even using 70% of RAM isn't outrageous. The linker tends to optimize heavily, so it is (probably) only including the routines you actually reference.

Comment: @NickGammon 10% was an arbitrary number, as I noticed intermittent issues when I got to this level of usage, of course that might not be related. The issue I saw was some times it would output all the values other times it would output nothing.

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove_Barometer_HP20x/blob/master/HP20x_dev/KalmanFilter.cpp) your `KalmanFilter`? I can't quite make sense out of it. To me, it looks silly and _very_ memory intensive. Couldn't you use a basic first-order low-pass instead?

Comment: You haven't replied to the first comment. Do you want to save RAM or PROGMEM? They have quite different purposes. You may have heap fragmentation due to your use of the **String** class which I suggest you stop using (as others have advised).

Comment: @NickGammon I have stopped using String and it seems to have improved the stability - I was trying to save PROGMEM

Comment: @EdgarBonet - yes thats the one, I dont have the experience on this - it was recommended as part of the sensor implimentation

Comment: Even if you used 99.9% of PROGMEM, that would not affect stability. However with string fragmentation (particularly caused by the String class) even 50% of RAM used might be too much. It looks like you have found the problem.

Comment: @NickGammon +1 your spot on. This looks like the root cause of the issue. I’m exploring alternative methods of sending the data now

Comment: @Rob. As you talk about PHP I think you're a software dev (like me). I suggest to have a look at the diff. between Harvard and Von Neumann architecture. Arduino is NOT a computer. Optimizing PHP code will give you more space (Von Neumann architecture) but optimizing the sketch will NOT give you more space for variable (Harvard architecture).

Comment: @Peter your too kind sir, I’m more a jack of all trades master of none. But your right I’m fast realising it’s quite a different arena to  work in and not all initially learned principles apply

Comment: Your use of the `F` macro (eg. `Serial.println(F("connected"));`) is very sensible. Without it, the compiler copies the string into RAM, further reducing available RAM. Done with the `F` macro the compiler generates code to pull the constant data directly from PROGMEM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I counted the floats in the sketch:

```
Global: 2
setup: 0
loop: 14
Total: 16 floats -> 64 bytes.
```

If you want to reduce that, don't wait to have all your values before preparing your answer. You will use less memory if you do

```
  data = String("dust=") + dht.readHumidity();
  data+= "&rs=" + (1023.0 / sensorValue) - 1;
  data+= "&hch0=" + pow(10.0, ((log10(Rs / R0) - 0.0827) / (-0.4807)));
  ... and the rest ...
```

Your `data` String and concat's take way more space than the floats. Use char[] instead of string.

As last resort, you don't need to construct the complete POST before sending it to the server. Send it line by line, value by value. Use a fixed, big enough `Content-Length:`,  padding with spaces after you send the values and know the actual lenght.

Or you can switch your technology: MQTT need way less memory than HTTP.

Comment: MQTT might be the ticket - I might send the value as soon as I have it

Comment: hmm interesting - I tried char data[15]; and the String("dust=") didn't like it - My understanding is data[] would now be an array - is that right?

Comment: @Rob. You use char[] instead of String(), not with or intermixed. You have to go low-level, char by char, byte by byte.

Comment: There have been some great responses on this question. It was hard to accept an answer, but as this one mentioned the String issue first I choose this one

Answer (score 2):

Two basic approaches:

1) use fixed point math. or

1) use int16_t or int32_t in lieu of the floating types. for example, you can use x10 or x100 to designate variables with some decimal points. use x16 or x128 or even x256 for speed gains as well. you will need to make sure that it doesn't overflow.

edit: here is an example that hopefully will help you get it going.

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    var1=100;               //var1=1.00
    var2=123;               //var2=1.23
}

void loop() {
    var1+=var2;             //increment var1
    Serial.print("var1 = "); Serial.print(var1 / 100); Serial.print("."); Serial.print(var1 - (var1 / 100) * 100); Serial.println(".");
    delay(100);
}
```

var1 (1.00 initially) is incremented by var2 (1.23), both are int32_t types.

here is the printout.

[image]

Comment: Ok so what you're saying is I can use int16_t  instead of a float? do I have to cast the result in some other way? doing more reading now

Comment: That’s pretty cool, never done this before. So var1 is of type int32_t. So when it’s taken to the string it’s only converted to the correct precision at the point - is this the essence of fixed point math?

Comment: So, are you using int32_t instead of float? Both are 4 bytes long.

Comment: @dannyf What software are you using in the last picture?  Is that an emulator?

Comment: " is this the essence of fixed point math?" yeah. fixed point math is in base 2, and what I have shown is in base 10. using base 2 speeds up calculation and using base 10 is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I second the advice that has already been given to you about avoiding
`String`. Other than that, using fixed-point math could be a big win,
but given the math you do it won't be any easy.

Assuming you stick with floating point, I just found a couple of easy
optimization opportunities:

- Do not use `pow` to evaluate a polynomial. Use the [Horner's
  method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) which is way
  cheaper: `d = ((1.1*ratio - 3.8)*ratio + 520)*ratio + 0.62`.
- The expression of ppm can be simplified:
  `ppm = 2500.33 * pow(Rs, -2.0803)`.

---

**Edit**: You could also try to implement [chunked transfer
encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). This
way you could send the data to the server on the fly, as you collet it,
instead of storing everything in memory and sending it in one go.

Example:

```c++
void send_chunk(Print &connection, const String &chunk)
{
    connection.println(chunk.length, 16);
    connection.println(chunk);
}

void loop() {
    // ...

    // last header sent to the client:
    client.println(F("Transfer-Encoding: chunked"));
    client.println();

    // Now the data:
    String chunk;
    chunk = "dust=";
    chunk += ((1.1*ratio - 3.8)*ratio + 520)*ratio + 0.62;
    send_chunk(client, chunk);
    chunk = "&rs=";
    chunk += Rs;
    send_chunk(client, chunk);
    chunk = "&hcho=";
    chunk += 2500.33 * pow(Rs, -2.0803);
    send_chunk(client, chunk);
    chunk = "&nh3=";
    chunk += gas.measure_NH3();
    send_chunk(client, chunk);
    // and so on...
    chunk = "";
    send_chunk(client, chunk);  // Empty chunk means end of message.

    // ...
}
```

Notice that there is no "Content-Length" header. Instead, each chunk is
preceded by its size in hex. And, most importantly, notice that this way
you can get rid of lots of variables.

---

**Edit 2**: I came out with a better (more generic) way to implement
chunked encoding, which involves sending the data through a “chunker”
filter that does the encoding and outputs to the client. Here is my
`Chunker` class:

```c++
/*
 * Transfer a message using the HTTP/1.1 "Chunked Transfer Coding".
 * C.f. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-4.1
 */
class Chunker : public Print
{
public:
    Chunker(Print &downstream) : downstream(downstream), pos(0) {}

    virtual size_t write(uint8_t c)
    {
        buffer[pos++] = c;
        if (pos == BUFFER_SIZE)
            send();
        return 1;
    }

    void end()
    {
        if (pos) send();
        send();  // empty chunk means end of message
    }

private:
    static const uint8_t BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
    Print &downstream;
    uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint8_t pos;

    // Send the buffer as a chunk.
    void send()
    {
        downstream.println(pos, HEX);
        if (pos) {
            downstream.write(buffer, pos);
            downstream.println();
            pos = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

And here is how you would use it:

```c++
Chunker message(client);  // instantiate the filter
message.print(F("dust="));
message.print(((1.1*ratio - 3.8)*ratio + 520)*ratio + 0.62);
message.print("&rs=");
message.print(Rs);
message.print(F("&hcho="));
message.print(2500.33 * pow(Rs, -2.0803));
message.print(F("&nh3="));
message.print(gas.measure_NH3());
// and so on...
message.end();  // terminate the chunked message
```

The main advantage of this method is that you completely avoid using the
`String` class, which means no dynamic memory allocation (a very
desirable thing). Also you can choose your buffer size. I've set it to
32 bytes, but you can make it smaller if needed.

Comment: @Rob: I added another suggestion about the usage of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Thats really cool - thank you for spending some time on this - I think im edging towards this approach

Comment: @Rob: Here is a more generic way of using chunked encoding, which avoids `String`, or even the need to guess how mush space you need to `sprintf()` a number.

Comment: Thats pretty amazing ... I just need to work out the particulars like the connection part. My Endpoint is a php page/server which does a load more things with the POST request - would this be a good place to start https://dancingmammoth.com/2009/08/29/php-stream-filters-unchunking-http-streams/

Comment: @Rob: I don't know much about PHP. Not sure whether you have to take for the encoding yourself. The link you provide is for adding chunked support to PHP _streams_, which are a useful tool for handling _very large_ payloads. You payload is tiny, so you don't need them. Also, I assume your web server will take care of the decoding step, at least if using mod\_php. Note, however, that [there is a PHP bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924004) that prevents this to work in fast CGI mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it’s really helped my understanding of what’s going on. I have found a link to send as a char array https://github.com/tttapa/Projects/blob/master/ESP8266/HTTP/HTTP-POST-char-array/HTTP-POST-char-array.ino - which should cut down my redevelopment of the receiver. This question has helped me hone in on the issue which I now believe was directly related to the dynamic allocation of the string. This was either blowing the dynamic memory or fragmenting the string variable, I noticed some times only half the string was posted. Thank you 